# IIS Express not Launching selected Project

Tags: asp.net, iis

I recently moved my office to another room in the house. Since moving my office, I've been having an issue debugging an ASP.NET web application with IIS Express. I right click my project, Debug, start new instance. When I do this, it appears to launch as normal, but it looks like it does not start up the selected project. It does, however, start up two related projects within the solution, and these run and operate successfully.

When it opens the chrome browser, it opens the usual address for the selected project that I tried to open (http://localhost:60788/), but it just says This site can’t be reached, as if the project did not launch.

In the task bar, I can see the running IIS Express applications, two related projects in the solution are running and working, but not the project I selected.

I can still publish the project successfully and everything works there, but I cannot use IIS Express locally anymore and I'm not sure why. What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

right click solution select property and click button Current selection

Answer (score 0):

It turns out something must have reserved the port that I had been using for the application this entire time. using the following:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

I could see an excluded port range included the port the instance was trying to use.

I could have tried to track down the process that was excluding these port ranges, however, to save time I just changed the port being used by the project. Properties -> Web, subsection Server. I entered a similar port that was not excluded as listed by the above command. Create Virtual Directory, Save. Working once again